# Module description string not parsed on first install

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, extensions

I'm using a language string in my module's XML file for the description:

```
...
<description>MOD_MYMODULE_DESC</description>
...
```

The first time I install the module, the string is NOT parsed:

[image: Module description]

If I re-install or update the extension, the complete text is loaded from the language file. How can I display the complete description also the first time the module is installed?

The language files are declared later in the XML file:

```
<languages>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_mymodule.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_mymodule.sys.ini</language>
    <language tag="es-ES">es-ES.mod_mymodule.ini</language>
    <language tag="es-ES">es-ES.mod_mymodule.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you defined `MOD_MYMODULE_DESC` in both the `.ini` **and** `sys.ini` files?

Comment: Yes, `sys.ini` defines only the name and the description (`MOD_MYMODULE` and `MOD_MYMODULE_DESC`), and the `.ini` file defines these and several other strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing, it appears that this happens when the language files are placed directly under the extension's root directory, and not inside a `/language/` folder.

If I move the language files to `/language/en-GB/` and `language/es-ES`, and modify the XML manifest like this, it works:

```
<languages folder="language">
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodule.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodule.sys.ini</language>
    <language tag="es-ES">es-ES/es-ES.mod_mymodule.ini</language>
    <language tag="es-ES">es-ES/es-ES.mod_mymodule.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

Now all strings are parsed, also on the initial installation.

Comment: Would be nice to know if you did try to keep the language files in the extension directory and remove the <languages..> part from the xml file?

Comment: I can confirm this behavior, the structure needs to be: "language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodule.sys.ini" Same goes for plugins (thats why i was here). Where the "en-GB" Subfolder is NOT optional when you want to have a postInstallation message on a fresh install.

Answer (score 3):

You can use several functions when a extension it's installed if you define a script in your xml...

```
<!-- Installation / uninstallation script file -->
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

Then you can use the renderPostInstallation() function in this file to render text or anything you want, this method always works...

Check the Akeeba backup extension for example it uses this script.

Comment: Thank you, that might be a better approach, I'll consider that. I'm still curious as to why the problem occurs, though.